# Javascript: Reducing Scriptaculous flickering using Effect Queues?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm just putting together a simple bit of Javascript using Prototype and Scriptaculous. It's very simple: Just fading a user quote out, switching it to another one, and then fading it back in. The problem is that Scriptaculous's fading is a bit flickery. I'm guessing this is because the fade out, switch, fade in, is happing so quickly that the browser is having difficulties keeping up.

At first I thought a pause would work, but now I've read you can use [Effect Queues](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-queues/) to fix this problem, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

Here's the original problematic code without any Effect Queues:

```
function fadeOut() {
new Effect.Opacity('quoteContainer', {from: 1.0, to: 0.0 });
}

function fadeIn() {
new Effect.Opacity('quoteContainer', {from: 0.0, to: 1.0 });
}

function changeQuote(i) {
    fadeOut();
    $('quote').innerHTML = quoteArray[i];
    $('name').innerHTML = nameArray[i];
    fadeIn();
}

changeQuote(0); // 1stQuo

window.onload = function () {
    var i = 1;
    var pause = setInterval(function () {
        changeQuote(i);
        i++;
        if (i>11) { i=0; } // Go to first quote in array
    }, 7000);
}
```

Unless, of course, anyone has a better idea of how to reduce the flickering?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () {
   fadeIn();
}, 500);
```

time in ms so thats 500 ms

Comment: That just really messed it up, I'm afraid :(

Comment: Discovered a thing called Effect Queues. Apparently Scriptaculous runs all effect simultaneously, and you need to tell it to wait.